# Any successful jsp websites in UK?

Tags: jsp

I would like to know if you can give me some webpages from UK, that are running on JSP and are well known in the public. I am specifically interested in UK not other countries, because of the job I am working on right now. Cannot tell the details yet ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this one will beat all other sites: http://www.ibm.com/uk/en/